I am trying achieve the given design in html css with text background
Design I want to achieve:

HTML and CSS code snippet:


* {
  align-items: center;
  /* background: black; */
}

.navbar .nav-items ul {
  gap: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .nav-items ul li a {
  color: white;
}

.nav-container {
  background: #151669;
}

.home-component {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.home-component h1 {
  display: table-caption;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(243, 57, 6, 0) 0%, rgba(250, 7, 7, 0) 61%), linear-gradient(rgb(238, 19, 19) 52%, rgb(239, 88, 18) 60%, rgb(234, 212, 23) 61%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: inline;
  width: 10vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container-fluid.home-component {
  position: relative;
}

.container-fluid.home-component h1 {
  font-size: 40vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Increased z-index for the text */
}

.container-fluid.home-component img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 1.5;
  /* Adjust the opacity as needed */
  z-index: 999999;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid.home-component h1 {
    font-size: 30vw;
    /* Adjust font size for smaller screens */
  }
  .container-fluid.home-component img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    opacity: 1.5;
    /* Adjust the opacity as needed */
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
<div class="container-fluid home-component bg-dark">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <h1>
        D<span>O</span>G
      </h1>
      <img src="./images/german-shepherd-2-1.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I am getting the output below:

I tried using z-index on the image, and gradient colour on the text but instead image is going backward or front trough which exact image design can't be achieved but I want this partially backward from bottom on front from top.
I have attached above the exact output I want to achieve and the things I have tried so far thanks in advance.

Use clip-path on the image. I'd use the image as a background if it's only there to illustrate the word dog and not new content, and put it on a clipped pseudo-element.

Fonts can render with subtle differences on different browsers & OS, so getting a clip-path exactly right here, might be a challenge. It might make more sense to create the whole thing in SVG.
